# Ansible: Dynamic list creation

Tags: ansible

I am trying to create a list on the fly during the playbook execution, as per the below code the list is not getting updated

```
- debug: var=builds[{{item}}]
  with_sequence: start={{ exactlen }} end={{ buildslen }}
- set_fact: upg_version_list = upg_version_list +  builds[{{item}}]
  with_sequence: start={{ exactlen }} end={{ buildslen }}
```

Here builds is a list, exactlen & buildslen are the index value of the list.

If i display the upg_version_list it has empty value

Answer (score 1):

1. `key=value` notation for parameters doesn't allow spaces between `=`.
2. right part of `set_fact` parameters is a string, so you should template it.

Try with:

```
- set_fact: upg_version_list="{{ upg_version_list + builds[item] }}"
  with_sequence: start={{ exactlen }} end={{ buildslen }}
```

Also you may want to use lists to add elements and default empty list for the first iteration:

```
{{ upg_version_list|default([]) + [builds[item]] }}
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. Unfortunately it didn't worked                                                      {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'list object' has no attribute u'44'..